# Not displaying KML on google earth app

Tags: android, google-maps, kml, google-earth

I'm starting my first Android app, so I'm a newbie in coding. I'm working on an app that tracks user's movement and displays polygons depending on speed and accelerations. I gather GPS and Acceleration data and process them to obtain the polygons (color and height). The problem is when I try to display the kml file on the Google Earth app, I can see the polygons if the view is really high (as a white line) but if I zoom in it displays nothing. Opening the kml file on the desktop computer with Google maps or Carto works (not displays height and color properly but at least I can see the shapes of the polygons.

This is an example KML file obtained during 1 test (I had to delete a lot of polygons because there is a bug with the generation that generates some latitudes and longitudes as NaN). Can you see the problem that makes Google Earth not displaying it?

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes' ?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
  <Document>
    <name>Mapa Smart Drive</name>
    <open>1</open>
    <Placemark>
      <name>Tramo 0</name>
      <description>-15 - -15</description>
      <Style>
        <LineStyle>
          <color>55464646</color>
          <width>1</width>
        </LineStyle>
        <PolyStyle>
          <color>648C8C8C</color>
          <fill>1</fill>
        </PolyStyle>
      </Style>
      <Polygon>
        <tessellate>1</tessellate>
        <extrude>1</extrude>
        <altitudeMode>relativeToGround</altitudeMode>
        <outerBoundaryIs>
          <LinearRing>
            <coordinates>-4.357478776365112,36.73126690778044,3.2 -4.357687929035563,36.731111695808195,3.2 -4.357682250964438,36.731103464191804,3.2 -4.357473343634887,36.73125851221957,3.2 -4.357478776365112,36.73126690778044,3.2</coordinates>
          </LinearRing>
        </outerBoundaryIs>
      </Polygon>
    </Placemark>
    <Placemark>
      <name>Tramo 0</name>
      <description>-15 - -15</description>
      <Style>
        <LineStyle>
          <color>55464646</color>
          <width>1</width>
        </LineStyle>
        <PolyStyle>
          <color>648C8C8C</color>
          <fill>1</fill>
        </PolyStyle>
      </Style>
      <Polygon>
        <tessellate>1</tessellate>
        <extrude>1</extrude>
        <altitudeMode>relativeToGround</altitudeMode>
        <outerBoundaryIs>
          <LinearRing>
            <coordinates>-4.357254545696953,36.73139240518886,3.2 -4.357478776365112,36.73126690778044,3.2 -4.357473343634887,36.73125851221957,3.2 -4.357249494303047,36.73138377481114,3.2 -4.357254545696953,36.73139240518886,3.2</coordinates>
          </LinearRing>
        </outerBoundaryIs>
      </Polygon>
    </Placemark>
    <Placemark>
      <name>Tramo 0</name>
      <description>-15 - -15</description>
      <Style>
        <LineStyle>
          <color>55464646</color>
          <width>1</width>
        </LineStyle>
        <PolyStyle>
          <color>648C8C8C</color>
          <fill>1</fill>
        </PolyStyle>
      </Style>
      <Polygon>
        <tessellate>1</tessellate>
        <extrude>1</extrude>
        <altitudeMode>relativeToGround</altitudeMode>
        <outerBoundaryIs>
          <LinearRing>
            <coordinates>-4.35703721738595,36.73152531632611,3.2 -4.357254545696953,36.73139240518886,3.2 -4.357249494303047,36.73138377481114,3.2 -4.3570320026140505,36.73151678367388,3.2 -4.35703721738595,36.73152531632611,3.2</coordinates>
          </LinearRing>
        </outerBoundaryIs>
      </Polygon>
    </Placemark>
    <Placemark>
      <name>Tramo 0</name>
      <description>-15 - -15</description>
      <Style>
        <LineStyle>
          <color>55464646</color>
          <width>1</width>
        </LineStyle>
        <PolyStyle>
          <color>648C8C8C</color>
          <fill>1</fill>
        </PolyStyle>
      </Style>
      <Polygon>
        <tessellate>1</tessellate>
        <extrude>1</extrude>
        <altitudeMode>relativeToGround</altitudeMode>
        <outerBoundaryIs>
          <LinearRing>
            <coordinates>-4.356849550352728,36.731639923144236,3.2 -4.35703721738595,36.73152531632611,3.2 -4.3570320026140505,36.73151678367388,3.2 -4.356844849647271,36.73163109685576,3.2 -4.356849550352728,36.731639923144236,3.2</coordinates>
          </LinearRing>
        </outerBoundaryIs>
      </Polygon>
    </Placemark>
    <Placemark>
      <name>Tramo 0</name>
      <description>-15 - -15</description>
      <Style>
        <LineStyle>
          <color>55464646</color>
          <width>1</width>
        </LineStyle>
        <PolyStyle>
          <color>648C8C8C</color>
          <fill>1</fill>
        </PolyStyle>
      </Style>
      <Polygon>
        <tessellate>1</tessellate>
        <extrude>1</extrude>
        <altitudeMode>relativeToGround</altitudeMode>
        <outerBoundaryIs>
          <LinearRing>
            <coordinates>-4.356605038973416,36.73175220292332,3.2 -4.356849550352728,36.731639923144236,3.2 -4.356844849647271,36.73163109685576,3.2 -4.356601181026584,36.73174297707668,3.2 -4.356605038973416,36.73175220292332,3.2</coordinates>
          </LinearRing>
        </outerBoundaryIs>
      </Polygon>
    </Placemark>
    <Placemark>
      <name>Tramo 0</name>
      <description>-15 - -15</description>
      <Style>
        <LineStyle>
          <color>55464646</color>
          <width>1</width>
        </LineStyle>
        <PolyStyle>
          <color>648C8C8C</color>
          <fill>1</fill>
        </PolyStyle>
      </Style>
      <Polygon>
        <tessellate>1</tessellate>
        <extrude>1</extrude>
        <altitudeMode>relativeToGround</altitudeMode>
        <outerBoundaryIs>
          <LinearRing>
            <coordinates>-4.3563474650969525,36.731849651056166,3.2 -4.356605038973416,36.73175220292332,3.2 -4.356601181026584,36.73174297707668,3.2 -4.356344114903047,36.73184022894384,3.2 -4.3563474650969525,36.731849651056166,3.2</coordinates>
          </LinearRing>
        </outerBoundaryIs>
      </Polygon>
    </Placemark>
    <Placemark>
      <name>Tramo 0</name>
      <description>-15 - -15</description>
      <Style>
        <LineStyle>
          <color>55464646</color>
          <width>1</width>
        </LineStyle>
        <PolyStyle>
          <color>648C8C8C</color>
          <fill>1</fill>
        </PolyStyle>
      </Style>
      <Polygon>
        <tessellate>1</tessellate>
        <extrude>1</extrude>
        <altitudeMode>relativeToGround</altitudeMode>
        <outerBoundaryIs>
          <LinearRing>
            <coordinates>-4.3560965707785195,36.73193323311166,3.2 -4.3563474650969525,36.731849651056166,3.2 -4.356344114903047,36.73184022894384,3.2 -4.356093529221481,36.73192370688834,3.2 -4.3560965707785195,36.73193323311166,3.2</coordinates>
          </LinearRing>
        </outerBoundaryIs>
      </Polygon>
    </Placemark>
    <Placemark>
      <name>Tramo 0</name>
      <description>-15 - -15</description>
      <Style>
        <LineStyle>
          <color>55464646</color>
          <width>1</width>
        </LineStyle>
        <PolyStyle>
          <color>648C8C8C</color>
          <fill>1</fill>
        </PolyStyle>
      </Style>
      <Polygon>
        <tessellate>1</tessellate>
        <extrude>1</extrude>
        <altitudeMode>relativeToGround</altitudeMode>
        <outerBoundaryIs>
          <LinearRing>
            <coordinates>-4.355819627704304,36.73201785066898,3.2 -4.3560965707785195,36.73193323311166,3.2 -4.356093529221481,36.73192370688834,3.2 -4.355816832295695,36.73200824933102,3.2 -4.355819627704304,36.73201785066898,3.2</coordinates>
          </LinearRing>
        </outerBoundaryIs>
      </Polygon>
    </Placemark>
    <Placemark>
      <name>Tramo 0</name>
      <description>-15 - -15</description>
      <Style>
        <LineStyle>
          <color>55464646</color>
          <width>1</width>
        </LineStyle>
        <PolyStyle>
          <color>648C8C8C</color>
          <fill>1</fill>
        </PolyStyle>
      </Style>
      <Polygon>
        <tessellate>1</tessellate>
        <extrude>1</extrude>
        <altitudeMode>relativeToGround</altitudeMode>
        <outerBoundaryIs>
          <LinearRing>
            <coordinates>-4.355554222486865,36.73209133076031,3.2 -4.355819627704304,36.73201785066898,3.2 -4.355816832295695,36.73200824933102,3.2 -4.355551797513136,36.73208162923969,3.2 -4.355554222486865,36.73209133076031,3.2</coordinates>
          </LinearRing>
        </outerBoundaryIs>
      </Polygon>
    </Placemark>
    <Placemark>
      <name>Tramo 0</name>
      <description>-15 - -15</description>
      <Style>
        <LineStyle>
          <color>55464646</color>
          <width>1</width>
        </LineStyle>
        <PolyStyle>
          <color>648C8C8C</color>
          <fill>1</fill>
        </PolyStyle>
      </Style>
      <Polygon>
        <tessellate>1</tessellate>
        <extrude>1</extrude>
        <altitudeMode>relativeToGround</altitudeMode>
        <outerBoundaryIs>
          <LinearRing>
            <coordinates>-4.355264387950788,36.73215607796105,3.2 -4.355554222486865,36.73209133076031,3.2 -4.355551797513136,36.73208162923969,3.2 -4.355262192049212,36.73214632203894,3.2 -4.355264387950788,36.73215607796105,3.2</coordinates>
          </LinearRing>
        </outerBoundaryIs>
      </Polygon>
    </Placemark>
    <Placemark>
      <name>Tramo 0</name>
      <description>-15 - -15</description>
      <Style>
        <LineStyle>
          <color>55464646</color>
          <width>1</width>
        </LineStyle>
        <PolyStyle>
          <color>648C8C8C</color>
          <fill>1</fill>
        </PolyStyle>
      </Style>
      <Polygon>
        <tessellate>1</tessellate>
        <extrude>1</extrude>
        <altitudeMode>relativeToGround</altitudeMode>
        <outerBoundaryIs>
          <LinearRing>
            <coordinates>-4.354996210305264,36.73221689479082,3.2 -4.355264387950788,36.73215607796105,3.2 -4.355262192049212,36.73214632203894,3.2 -4.354994169694737,36.73220710520918,3.2 -4.354996210305264,36.73221689479082,3.2</coordinates>
          </LinearRing>
        </outerBoundaryIs>
      </Polygon>
    </Placemark>
    <Placemark>
      <name>Tramo 0</name>
      <description>-15 - -15</description>
      <Style>
        <LineStyle>
          <color>55464646</color>
          <width>1</width>
        </LineStyle>
        <PolyStyle>
          <color>648C8C8C</color>
          <fill>1</fill>
        </PolyStyle>
      </Style>
      <Polygon>
        <tessellate>1</tessellate>
        <extrude>1</extrude>
        <altitudeMode>relativeToGround</altitudeMode>
        <outerBoundaryIs>
          <LinearRing>
            <coordinates>-4.354724263773596,36.73226862976462,3.2 -4.354996210305264,36.73221689479082,3.2 -4.354994169694737,36.73220710520918,3.2 -4.354722716226403,36.73225875023539,3.2 -4.354724263773596,36.73226862976462,3.2</coordinates>
          </LinearRing>
        </outerBoundaryIs>
      </Polygon>
    </Placemark>
    <Placemark>
      <name>Tramo 0</name>
      <description>-15 - -15</description>
      <Style>
        <LineStyle>
          <color>55464646</color>
          <width>1</width>
        </LineStyle>
        <PolyStyle>
          <color>648C8C8C</color>
          <fill>1</fill>
        </PolyStyle>
      </Style>
      <Polygon>
        <tessellate>1</tessellate>
        <extrude>1</extrude>
        <altitudeMode>relativeToGround</altitudeMode>
        <outerBoundaryIs>
          <LinearRing>
            <coordinates>-4.354454851663621,36.73230186955821,3.3 -4.354724263773596,36.73226862976462,3.2 -4.354722716226403,36.73225875023539,3.2 -4.354453948336379,36.73229191044179,3.3 -4.354454851663621,36.73230186955821,3.3</coordinates>
          </LinearRing>
        </outerBoundaryIs>
      </Polygon>
    </Placemark>
    <Placemark>
      <name>Tramo 0</name>
      <description>-15 - -15</description>
      <Style>
        <LineStyle>
          <color>55464646</color>
          <width>1</width>
        </LineStyle>
        <PolyStyle>
          <color>648C8C8C</color>
          <fill>1</fill>
        </PolyStyle>
      </Style>
      <Polygon>
        <tessellate>1</tessellate>
        <extrude>1</extrude>
        <altitudeMode>relativeToGround</altitudeMode>
        <outerBoundaryIs>
          <LinearRing>
            <coordinates>-4.35414995267204,36.73231962309557,3.3 -4.354454851663621,36.73230186955821,3.3 -4.354453948336379,36.73229191044179,3.3 -4.354149427327959,36.732309636904425,3.3 -4.35414995267204,36.73231962309557,3.3</coordinates>
          </LinearRing>
        </outerBoundaryIs>
      </Polygon>
    </Placemark>
    <Placemark>
      <name>Tramo 0</name>
      <description>-15 - -15</description>
      <Style>
        <LineStyle>
          <color>55464646</color>
          <width>1</width>
        </LineStyle>
        <PolyStyle>
          <color>648C8C8C</color>
          <fill>1</fill>
        </PolyStyle>
      </Style>
      <Polygon>
        <tessellate>1</tessellate>
        <extrude>1</extrude>
        <altitudeMode>relativeToGround</altitudeMode>
        <outerBoundaryIs>
          <LinearRing>
            <coordinates>-4.353862999728337,36.73233310831677,3.2 -4.35414995267204,36.73231962309557,3.3 -4.354149427327959,36.732309636904425,3.3 -4.353862740271664,36.73232311168322,3.2 -4.353862999728337,36.73233310831677,3.2</coordinates>
          </LinearRing>
        </outerBoundaryIs>
      </Polygon>
    </Placemark>
    <Placemark>
      <name>Tramo 0</name>
      <description>-15 - -15</description>
      <Style>
        <LineStyle>
          <color>55464646</color>
          <width>1</width>
        </LineStyle>
        <PolyStyle>
          <color>648C8C8C</color>
          <fill>1</fill>
        </PolyStyle>
      </Style>
      <Polygon>
        <tessellate>1</tessellate>
        <extrude>1</extrude>
        <altitudeMode>relativeToGround</altitudeMode>
        <outerBoundaryIs>
          <LinearRing>
            <coordinates>-4.353575095000928,36.73233452979749,3.2 -4.353862999728337,36.73233310831677,3.2 -4.353862740271664,36.73232311168322,3.2 -4.353575004999072,36.73232453020251,3.2 -4.353575095000928,36.73233452979749,3.2</coordinates>
          </LinearRing>
        </outerBoundaryIs>
      </Polygon>
    </Placemark>
    <Placemark>
      <name>Tramo 0</name>
      <description>-15 - -15</description>
      <Style>
        <LineStyle>
          <color>55464646</color>
          <width>1</width>
        </LineStyle>
        <PolyStyle>
          <color>648C8C8C</color>
          <fill>1</fill>
        </PolyStyle>
      </Style>
      <Polygon>
        <tessellate>1</tessellate>
        <extrude>1</extrude>
        <altitudeMode>relativeToGround</altitudeMode>
        <outerBoundaryIs>
          <LinearRing>
            <coordinates>-4.353306505546209,36.732338039691456,3.2 -4.353575095000928,36.73233452979749,3.2 -4.353575004999072,36.73232453020251,3.2 -4.35330639445379,36.732328040308545,3.2 -4.353306505546209,36.732338039691456,3.2</coordinates>
          </LinearRing>
        </outerBoundaryIs>
      </Polygon>
    </Placemark>
    <Placemark>
      <name>Tramo 0</name>
      <description>-15 - -15</description>
      <Style>
        <LineStyle>
          <color>55464646</color>
          <width>1</width>
        </LineStyle>
        <PolyStyle>
          <color>648C8C8C</color>
          <fill>1</fill>
        </PolyStyle>
      </Style>
      <Polygon>
        <tessellate>1</tessellate>
        <extrude>1</extrude>
        <altitudeMode>relativeToGround</altitudeMode>
        <outerBoundaryIs>
          <LinearRing>
            <coordinates>-4.3530245050666325,36.732340619798094,3.2 -4.353306505546209,36.732338039691456,3.2 -4.35330639445379,36.732328040308545,3.2 -4.353024594933367,36.73233062020191,3.2 -4.3530245050666325,36.732340619798094,3.2</coordinates>
          </LinearRing>
        </outerBoundaryIs>
      </Polygon>
    </Placemark>
    <Placemark>
      <name>Tramo 0</name>
      <description>-15 - -15</description>
      <Style>
        <LineStyle>
          <color>55464646</color>
          <width>1</width>
        </LineStyle>
        <PolyStyle>
          <color>648C8C8C</color>
          <fill>1</fill>
        </PolyStyle>
      </Style>
      <Polygon>
        <tessellate>1</tessellate>
        <extrude>1</extrude>
        <altitudeMode>relativeToGround</altitudeMode>
        <outerBoundaryIs>
          <LinearRing>
            <coordinates>-4.3530245050666325,36.732340619798094,3.2 -4.353024594933367,36.73233062020191,3.2 -4.352723943824105,36.732322462068964,3.3 -4.352723656175894,36.73233245793104,3.3 -4.3530245050666325,36.732340619798094,3.2</coordinates>
          </LinearRing>
        </outerBoundaryIs>
      </Polygon>
    </Placemark>
    <Placemark>
      <name>Tramo 0</name>
      <description>-15 - -15</description>
      <Style>
        <LineStyle>
          <color>55464646</color>
          <width>1</width>
        </LineStyle>
        <PolyStyle>
          <color>648C8C8C</color>
          <fill>1</fill>
        </PolyStyle>
      </Style>
      <Polygon>
        <tessellate>1</tessellate>
        <extrude>1</extrude>
        <altitudeMode>relativeToGround</altitudeMode>
        <outerBoundaryIs>
          <LinearRing>
            <coordinates>-4.352723656175894,36.73233245793104,3.3 -4.352723943824105,36.732322462068964,3.3 -4.35245015992842,36.732314133238475,3.3 -4.3524498000715806,36.732324126761526,3.3 -4.352723656175894,36.73233245793104,3.3</coordinates>
          </LinearRing>
        </outerBoundaryIs>
      </Polygon>
    </Placemark>
    <Placemark>
      <name>Tramo 0</name>
      <description>-15 - -15</description>
      <Style>
        <LineStyle>
          <color>55464646</color>
          <width>1</width>
        </LineStyle>
        <PolyStyle>
          <color>648C8C8C</color>
          <fill>1</fill>
        </PolyStyle>
      </Style>
      <Polygon>
        <tessellate>1</tessellate>
        <extrude>1</extrude>
        <altitudeMode>relativeToGround</altitudeMode>
        <outerBoundaryIs>
          <LinearRing>
            <coordinates>-4.3524498000715806,36.732324126761526,3.3 -4.35245015992842,36.732314133238475,3.3 -4.352180125631036,36.73230290196039,3.2 -4.352179434368964,36.732312878039615,3.2 -4.3524498000715806,36.732324126761526,3.3</coordinates>
          </LinearRing>
        </outerBoundaryIs>
      </Polygon>
    </Placemark>
  </Document>
</kml>
```

Comment: I'va added the visibility tag and removed the fill and it is still doing the same, no change. Anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is using the exact same color as the road, that's why you can't see it.

Changing the colors to red will make the lines visible.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes' ?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
  <Document>
    <name>Mapa Smart Drive</name>
    <open>1</open>
    <Placemark>
      <name>Tramo 0</name>
      <description>-15 - -15</description>
      <Style>
        <LineStyle>
          <color>501400FF</color>
          <width>1</width>
        </LineStyle>
        <PolyStyle>
          <color>501400FF</color>
          <fill>1</fill>
        </PolyStyle>
      </Style>
      <Polygon>
        <tessellate>1</tessellate>
        <extrude>1</extrude>
        <altitudeMode>relativeToGround</altitudeMode>
        <outerBoundaryIs>
          <LinearRing>
            <coordinates>-4.357478776365112,36.73126690778044,3.2 -4.357687929035563,36.731111695808195,3.2 -4.357682250964438,36.731103464191804,3.2 -4.357473343634887,36.73125851221957,3.2 -4.357478776365112,36.73126690778044,3.2</coordinates>
          </LinearRing>
        </outerBoundaryIs>
      </Polygon>
    </Placemark>
    <Placemark>
      <name>Tramo 0</name>
      <description>-15 - -15</description>
      <Style>
        <LineStyle>
          <color>501400FF</color>
          <width>1</width>
        </LineStyle>
        <PolyStyle>
          <color>501400FF</color>
          <fill>1</fill>
        </PolyStyle>
      </Style>
      <Polygon>
        <tessellate>1</tessellate>
        <extrude>1</extrude>
        <altitudeMode>relativeToGround</altitudeMode>
        <outerBoundaryIs>
          <LinearRing>
            <coordinates>-4.357254545696953,36.73139240518886,3.2 -4.357478776365112,36.73126690778044,3.2 -4.357473343634887,36.73125851221957,3.2 -4.357249494303047,36.73138377481114,3.2 -4.357254545696953,36.73139240518886,3.2</coordinates>
          </LinearRing>
        </outerBoundaryIs>
      </Polygon>
    </Placemark>
    <Placemark>
      <name>Tramo 0</name>
      <description>-15 - -15</description>
      <Style>
        <LineStyle>
          <color>501400FF</color>
          <width>1</width>
        </LineStyle>
        <PolyStyle>
          <color>501400FF</color>
          <fill>1</fill>
        </PolyStyle>
      </Style>
      <Polygon>
        <tessellate>1</tessellate>
        <extrude>1</extrude>
        <altitudeMode>relativeToGround</altitudeMode>
        <outerBoundaryIs>
          <LinearRing>
            <coordinates>-4.35703721738595,36.73152531632611,3.2 -4.357254545696953,36.73139240518886,3.2 -4.357249494303047,36.73138377481114,3.2 -4.3570320026140505,36.73151678367388,3.2 -4.35703721738595,36.73152531632611,3.2</coordinates>
          </LinearRing>
        </outerBoundaryIs>
      </Polygon>
    </Placemark>
    <Placemark>
      <name>Tramo 0</name>
      <description>-15 - -15</description>
      <Style>
        <LineStyle>
          <color>501400FF</color>
          <width>1</width>
        </LineStyle>
        <PolyStyle>
          <color>501400FF</color>
          <fill>1</fill>
        </PolyStyle>
      </Style>
      <Polygon>
        <tessellate>1</tessellate>
        <extrude>1</extrude>
        <altitudeMode>relativeToGround</altitudeMode>
        <outerBoundaryIs>
          <LinearRing>
            <coordinates>-4.356849550352728,36.731639923144236,3.2 -4.35703721738595,36.73152531632611,3.2 -4.3570320026140505,36.73151678367388,3.2 -4.356844849647271,36.73163109685576,3.2 -4.356849550352728,36.731639923144236,3.2</coordinates>
          </LinearRing>
        </outerBoundaryIs>
      </Polygon>
    </Placemark>
    <Placemark>
      <name>Tramo 0</name>
      <description>-15 - -15</description>
      <Style>
        <LineStyle>
          <color>501400FF</color>
          <width>1</width>
        </LineStyle>
        <PolyStyle>
          <color>501400FF</color>
          <fill>1</fill>
        </PolyStyle>
      </Style>
      <Polygon>
        <tessellate>1</tessellate>
        <extrude>1</extrude>
        <altitudeMode>relativeToGround</altitudeMode>
        <outerBoundaryIs>
          <LinearRing>
            <coordinates>-4.356605038973416,36.73175220292332,3.2 -4.356849550352728,36.731639923144236,3.2 -4.356844849647271,36.73163109685576,3.2 -4.356601181026584,36.73174297707668,3.2 -4.356605038973416,36.73175220292332,3.2</coordinates>
          </LinearRing>
        </outerBoundaryIs>
      </Polygon>
    </Placemark>
    <Placemark>
      <name>Tramo 0</name>
      <description>-15 - -15</description>
      <Style>
        <LineStyle>
          <color>501400FF</color>
          <width>1</width>
        </LineStyle>
        <PolyStyle>
          <color>501400FF</color>
          <fill>1</fill>
        </PolyStyle>
      </Style>
      <Polygon>
        <tessellate>1</tessellate>
        <extrude>1</extrude>
        <altitudeMode>relativeToGround</altitudeMode>
        <outerBoundaryIs>
          <LinearRing>
            <coordinates>-4.3563474650969525,36.731849651056166,3.2 -4.356605038973416,36.73175220292332,3.2 -4.356601181026584,36.73174297707668,3.2 -4.356344114903047,36.73184022894384,3.2 -4.3563474650969525,36.731849651056166,3.2</coordinates>
          </LinearRing>
        </outerBoundaryIs>
      </Polygon>
    </Placemark>
    <Placemark>
      <name>Tramo 0</name>
      <description>-15 - -15</description>
      <Style>
        <LineStyle>
          <color>501400FF</color>
          <width>1</width>
        </LineStyle>
        <PolyStyle>
          <color>501400FF</color>
          <fill>1</fill>
        </PolyStyle>
      </Style>
      <Polygon>
        <tessellate>1</tessellate>
        <extrude>1</extrude>
        <altitudeMode>relativeToGround</altitudeMode>
        <outerBoundaryIs>
          <LinearRing>
            <coordinates>-4.3560965707785195,36.73193323311166,3.2 -4.3563474650969525,36.731849651056166,3.2 -4.356344114903047,36.73184022894384,3.2 -4.356093529221481,36.73192370688834,3.2 -4.3560965707785195,36.73193323311166,3.2</coordinates>
          </LinearRing>
        </outerBoundaryIs>
      </Polygon>
    </Placemark>
    <Placemark>
      <name>Tramo 0</name>
      <description>-15 - -15</description>
      <Style>
        <LineStyle>
          <color>501400FF</color>
          <width>1</width>
        </LineStyle>
        <PolyStyle>
          <color>501400FF</color>
          <fill>1</fill>
        </PolyStyle>
      </Style>
      <Polygon>
        <tessellate>1</tessellate>
        <extrude>1</extrude>
        <altitudeMode>relativeToGround</altitudeMode>
        <outerBoundaryIs>
          <LinearRing>
            <coordinates>-4.355819627704304,36.73201785066898,3.2 -4.3560965707785195,36.73193323311166,3.2 -4.356093529221481,36.73192370688834,3.2 -4.355816832295695,36.73200824933102,3.2 -4.355819627704304,36.73201785066898,3.2</coordinates>
          </LinearRing>
        </outerBoundaryIs>
      </Polygon>
    </Placemark>
    <Placemark>
      <name>Tramo 0</name>
      <description>-15 - -15</description>
      <Style>
        <LineStyle>
          <color>501400FF</color>
          <width>1</width>
        </LineStyle>
        <PolyStyle>
          <color>501400FF</color>
          <fill>1</fill>
        </PolyStyle>
      </Style>
      <Polygon>
        <tessellate>1</tessellate>
        <extrude>1</extrude>
        <altitudeMode>relativeToGround</altitudeMode>
        <outerBoundaryIs>
          <LinearRing>
            <coordinates>-4.355554222486865,36.73209133076031,3.2 -4.355819627704304,36.73201785066898,3.2 -4.355816832295695,36.73200824933102,3.2 -4.355551797513136,36.73208162923969,3.2 -4.355554222486865,36.73209133076031,3.2</coordinates>
          </LinearRing>
        </outerBoundaryIs>
      </Polygon>
    </Placemark>
    <Placemark>
      <name>Tramo 0</name>
      <description>-15 - -15</description>
      <Style>
        <LineStyle>
          <color>501400FF</color>
          <width>1</width>
        </LineStyle>
        <PolyStyle>
          <color>501400FF</color>
          <fill>1</fill>
        </PolyStyle>
      </Style>
      <Polygon>
        <tessellate>1</tessellate>
        <extrude>1</extrude>
        <altitudeMode>relativeToGround</altitudeMode>
        <outerBoundaryIs>
          <LinearRing>
            <coordinates>-4.355264387950788,36.73215607796105,3.2 -4.355554222486865,36.73209133076031,3.2 -4.355551797513136,36.73208162923969,3.2 -4.355262192049212,36.73214632203894,3.2 -4.355264387950788,36.73215607796105,3.2</coordinates>
          </LinearRing>
        </outerBoundaryIs>
      </Polygon>
    </Placemark>
    <Placemark>
      <name>Tramo 0</name>
      <description>-15 - -15</description>
      <Style>
        <LineStyle>
          <color>501400FF</color>
          <width>1</width>
        </LineStyle>
        <PolyStyle>
          <color>501400FF</color>
          <fill>1</fill>
        </PolyStyle>
      </Style>
      <Polygon>
        <tessellate>1</tessellate>
        <extrude>1</extrude>
        <altitudeMode>relativeToGround</altitudeMode>
        <outerBoundaryIs>
          <LinearRing>
            <coordinates>-4.354996210305264,36.73221689479082,3.2 -4.355264387950788,36.73215607796105,3.2 -4.355262192049212,36.73214632203894,3.2 -4.354994169694737,36.73220710520918,3.2 -4.354996210305264,36.73221689479082,3.2</coordinates>
          </LinearRing>
        </outerBoundaryIs>
      </Polygon>
    </Placemark>
    <Placemark>
      <name>Tramo 0</name>
      <description>-15 - -15</description>
      <Style>
        <LineStyle>
          <color>501400FF</color>
          <width>1</width>
        </LineStyle>
        <PolyStyle>
          <color>501400FF</color>
          <fill>1</fill>
        </PolyStyle>
      </Style>
      <Polygon>
        <tessellate>1</tessellate>
        <extrude>1</extrude>
        <altitudeMode>relativeToGround</altitudeMode>
        <outerBoundaryIs>
          <LinearRing>
            <coordinates>-4.354724263773596,36.73226862976462,3.2 -4.354996210305264,36.73221689479082,3.2 -4.354994169694737,36.73220710520918,3.2 -4.354722716226403,36.73225875023539,3.2 -4.354724263773596,36.73226862976462,3.2</coordinates>
          </LinearRing>
        </outerBoundaryIs>
      </Polygon>
    </Placemark>
    <Placemark>
      <name>Tramo 0</name>
      <description>-15 - -15</description>
      <Style>
        <LineStyle>
          <color>501400FF</color>
          <width>1</width>
        </LineStyle>
        <PolyStyle>
          <color>501400FF</color>
          <fill>1</fill>
        </PolyStyle>
      </Style>
      <Polygon>
        <tessellate>1</tessellate>
        <extrude>1</extrude>
        <altitudeMode>relativeToGround</altitudeMode>
        <outerBoundaryIs>
          <LinearRing>
            <coordinates>-4.354454851663621,36.73230186955821,3.3 -4.354724263773596,36.73226862976462,3.2 -4.354722716226403,36.73225875023539,3.2 -4.354453948336379,36.73229191044179,3.3 -4.354454851663621,36.73230186955821,3.3</coordinates>
          </LinearRing>
        </outerBoundaryIs>
      </Polygon>
    </Placemark>
    <Placemark>
      <name>Tramo 0</name>
      <description>-15 - -15</description>
      <Style>
        <LineStyle>
          <color>501400FF</color>
          <width>1</width>
        </LineStyle>
        <PolyStyle>
          <color>501400FF</color>
          <fill>1</fill>
        </PolyStyle>
      </Style>
      <Polygon>
        <tessellate>1</tessellate>
        <extrude>1</extrude>
        <altitudeMode>relativeToGround</altitudeMode>
        <outerBoundaryIs>
          <LinearRing>
            <coordinates>-4.35414995267204,36.73231962309557,3.3 -4.354454851663621,36.73230186955821,3.3 -4.354453948336379,36.73229191044179,3.3 -4.354149427327959,36.732309636904425,3.3 -4.35414995267204,36.73231962309557,3.3</coordinates>
          </LinearRing>
        </outerBoundaryIs>
      </Polygon>
    </Placemark>
    <Placemark>
      <name>Tramo 0</name>
      <description>-15 - -15</description>
      <Style>
        <LineStyle>
          <color>501400FF</color>
          <width>1</width>
        </LineStyle>
        <PolyStyle>
          <color>501400FF</color>
          <fill>1</fill>
        </PolyStyle>
      </Style>
      <Polygon>
        <tessellate>1</tessellate>
        <extrude>1</extrude>
        <altitudeMode>relativeToGround</altitudeMode>
        <outerBoundaryIs>
          <LinearRing>
            <coordinates>-4.353862999728337,36.73233310831677,3.2 -4.35414995267204,36.73231962309557,3.3 -4.354149427327959,36.732309636904425,3.3 -4.353862740271664,36.73232311168322,3.2 -4.353862999728337,36.73233310831677,3.2</coordinates>
          </LinearRing>
        </outerBoundaryIs>
      </Polygon>
    </Placemark>
    <Placemark>
      <name>Tramo 0</name>
      <description>-15 - -15</description>
      <Style>
        <LineStyle>
          <color>501400FF</color>
          <width>1</width>
        </LineStyle>
        <PolyStyle>
          <color>501400FF</color>
          <fill>1</fill>
        </PolyStyle>
      </Style>
      <Polygon>
        <tessellate>1</tessellate>
        <extrude>1</extrude>
        <altitudeMode>relativeToGround</altitudeMode>
        <outerBoundaryIs>
          <LinearRing>
            <coordinates>-4.353575095000928,36.73233452979749,3.2 -4.353862999728337,36.73233310831677,3.2 -4.353862740271664,36.73232311168322,3.2 -4.353575004999072,36.73232453020251,3.2 -4.353575095000928,36.73233452979749,3.2</coordinates>
          </LinearRing>
        </outerBoundaryIs>
      </Polygon>
    </Placemark>
    <Placemark>
      <name>Tramo 0</name>
      <description>-15 - -15</description>
      <Style>
        <LineStyle>
          <color>501400FF</color>
          <width>1</width>
        </LineStyle>
        <PolyStyle>
          <color>501400FF</color>
          <fill>1</fill>
        </PolyStyle>
      </Style>
      <Polygon>
        <tessellate>1</tessellate>
        <extrude>1</extrude>
        <altitudeMode>relativeToGround</altitudeMode>
        <outerBoundaryIs>
          <LinearRing>
            <coordinates>-4.353306505546209,36.732338039691456,3.2 -4.353575095000928,36.73233452979749,3.2 -4.353575004999072,36.73232453020251,3.2 -4.35330639445379,36.732328040308545,3.2 -4.353306505546209,36.732338039691456,3.2</coordinates>
          </LinearRing>
        </outerBoundaryIs>
      </Polygon>
    </Placemark>
    <Placemark>
      <name>Tramo 0</name>
      <description>-15 - -15</description>
      <Style>
        <LineStyle>
          <color>501400FF</color>
          <width>1</width>
        </LineStyle>
        <PolyStyle>
          <color>501400FF</color>
          <fill>1</fill>
        </PolyStyle>
      </Style>
      <Polygon>
        <tessellate>1</tessellate>
        <extrude>1</extrude>
        <altitudeMode>relativeToGround</altitudeMode>
        <outerBoundaryIs>
          <LinearRing>
            <coordinates>-4.3530245050666325,36.732340619798094,3.2 -4.353306505546209,36.732338039691456,3.2 -4.35330639445379,36.732328040308545,3.2 -4.353024594933367,36.73233062020191,3.2 -4.3530245050666325,36.732340619798094,3.2</coordinates>
          </LinearRing>
        </outerBoundaryIs>
      </Polygon>
    </Placemark>
    <Placemark>
      <name>Tramo 0</name>
      <description>-15 - -15</description>
      <Style>
        <LineStyle>
          <color>501400FF</color>
          <width>1</width>
        </LineStyle>
        <PolyStyle>
          <color>501400FF</color>
          <fill>1</fill>
        </PolyStyle>
      </Style>
      <Polygon>
        <tessellate>1</tessellate>
        <extrude>1</extrude>
        <altitudeMode>relativeToGround</altitudeMode>
        <outerBoundaryIs>
          <LinearRing>
            <coordinates>-4.3530245050666325,36.732340619798094,3.2 -4.353024594933367,36.73233062020191,3.2 -4.352723943824105,36.732322462068964,3.3 -4.352723656175894,36.73233245793104,3.3 -4.3530245050666325,36.732340619798094,3.2</coordinates>
          </LinearRing>
        </outerBoundaryIs>
      </Polygon>
    </Placemark>
    <Placemark>
      <name>Tramo 0</name>
      <description>-15 - -15</description>
      <Style>
        <LineStyle>
          <color>501400FF</color>
          <width>1</width>
        </LineStyle>
        <PolyStyle>
          <color>501400FF</color>
          <fill>1</fill>
        </PolyStyle>
      </Style>
      <Polygon>
        <tessellate>1</tessellate>
        <extrude>1</extrude>
        <altitudeMode>relativeToGround</altitudeMode>
        <outerBoundaryIs>
          <LinearRing>
            <coordinates>-4.352723656175894,36.73233245793104,3.3 -4.352723943824105,36.732322462068964,3.3 -4.35245015992842,36.732314133238475,3.3 -4.3524498000715806,36.732324126761526,3.3 -4.352723656175894,36.73233245793104,3.3</coordinates>
          </LinearRing>
        </outerBoundaryIs>
      </Polygon>
    </Placemark>
    <Placemark>
      <name>Tramo 0</name>
      <description>-15 - -15</description>
      <Style>
        <LineStyle>
          <color>501400FF</color>
          <width>1</width>
        </LineStyle>
        <PolyStyle>
          <color>501400FF</color>
          <fill>1</fill>
        </PolyStyle>
      </Style>
      <Polygon>
        <tessellate>1</tessellate>
        <extrude>1</extrude>
        <altitudeMode>relativeToGround</altitudeMode>
        <outerBoundaryIs>
          <LinearRing>
            <coordinates>-4.3524498000715806,36.732324126761526,3.3 -4.35245015992842,36.732314133238475,3.3 -4.352180125631036,36.73230290196039,3.2 -4.352179434368964,36.732312878039615,3.2 -4.3524498000715806,36.732324126761526,3.3</coordinates>
          </LinearRing>
        </outerBoundaryIs>
      </Polygon>
    </Placemark>
  </Document>
</kml>
```